# OpenCV findHomography errors

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm using the SURF feature detection of OpenCV to compare two images. 
When I choose two identical images (sometimes the same image chosen), I get this:

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_IS_MAT(imagePoints) && CV_IS_MAT(objectPoints)) in cvFindHomography, file /home/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 232 
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing 
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must 
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there. 

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' 
what(): /home/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:232: error: (-215) CV_IS_MAT(imagePoints) && CV_IS_MAT(objectPoints) in function cvFindHomography 

Le programme s'est terminé subitement
```

A second execution of the code with two different images says that:

```
what(): /home/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp:235: error: (-215) count >= 4 in function cvFindHomography
```

I repeated the execution many times with differente images every time, and some test gave me the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have enough amount of points to calculate a homography. You need at least 4 points to do this and the amount of points you match needs to be equal (`imagePoints` and `objectPoints`). See the [reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#Mat%20findHomography%28InputArray%20srcPoints,%20InputArray%20dstPoints,%20int%20method,%20double%20ransacReprojThreshold,%20OutputArray%20mask%29) for an explanation.